# Integrating $\int_0^1 \cos(x+\cos x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The only way I can think of getting started is via the sub $u=\cos x$ and using the compound angle formula, which yields:
$$\int_1^{\cos 1} \left( \sin u - \frac u {\sqrt{1-u^2}}\cos u\right) du
=\cos 1 - \cos\cos 1 + \lim_{a\to 1}\int_{\cos 1}^a\frac {u\cos u} {\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$

Now I'm not sure about this new integral. I've tried integration by parts:

$$ =\lim_{a\to 1}\left\{\left[\frac {u\cos u} {\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right]_{\cos 1}^a - \int_{\cos 1}^a 
\frac {\cos u} {\sqrt{1-u^2}} du \right\} $$

but the resulting integral isn't any easier to solve. If I instead integrate $\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ and differentiate $\cos u$ then I get:

$$ =\lim_{a\to 1}\left\{ \left[\cos u \arcsin u\right]_{\cos 1}^a + \int_{\cos 1}^a \arcsin u \sin u du \right\} $$

If I substitute $w=\sqrt{1-u^2}$ then I get:
$$\int_{\sin 1}^0 \cos\sqrt{1-w^2}dw$$

None of these integrals look any better than the one I'm trying to solve. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: I'd be shocked if this were doable in some sort of reasonable closed form.

Comment: It was provided to an acquaintance as an interview question so I believe there should be a reasonable solution.

Comment: If the upper bound were $\pi$, then it would have a simple closed form with a Bessel type function, but the $1$ is not like this. Is a series expansion ok?

Comment: That's fine, but maybe I'm being silly but wouldn't a series expansion fail as $(1-u^2)^{-1/2}$ has a series that only converges for $0\leq u<1$, but this integral includes 1 in its limits?

Comment: @PearApple Try a [Jacobi anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) or expand $\cos(y)$ as a series after using the $\cos(a+b)$ formula

Answer (score 3):

Using Jacobi-Anger, we proceed as follows:
$$\int_0^1 \cos x \cos \cos x - \sin x \sin \cos x dx$$
$$=\int_0^1 \cos x \left[J_0(1)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n}(1)\cos(2nx)\right]-\sin x \left[-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(1)\cos (2n-1)x\right] dx$$
$$=\int_0^1J_0(1)\cos xdx+2\int_0^1\cos x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n}(1)\cos 2nx dx+2\int_0^1\sin x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(1)\cos(2n-1)xdx$$
$$=J_0(1)\sin 1+2\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n}(1)\cos x\cos(2nx) dx+2\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(1)\sin x\cos (2n-1)x dx$$
I don't know enough real analysis to show that the sums above converge absolutely so I shall assume that they do and that I can swap the sum and integral signs:
$$=J_0(1)\sin 1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n}(1)\int_0^1\cos x \cos 2nx dx + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(1)\int_0^1\sin x\cos (2n-1)x dx$$
which simplifies to
$$=J_0(1)\sin 1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n}(1)\frac {\sin 1\cos 2n-2n\cos 1\sin 2n} {1-4n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(1)\frac {\sin^2n+n\sin1\sin(1-2n)} {2n(1-n)}$$
I don't think this can be further simplified, combining the summations would probably make this even more complicated so I shall leave it like this.

EDIT: Just noticed that the second sum diverges when $n=1$ when it shouldn't so I shall isolate the $n=1$ cases from the rest of the sums. $\int_0^1 \cos x \cos 2x dx=\frac 1 6 (3\sin 1 + \sin 3)$ and $\int_0^1 \sin x \cos x dx= \frac 1 2 \sin^2 1$ so we get overall:

$$=J_0(1)\sin 1 -J_1(1)\sin^2 1 - \frac {J_2(1)} 3 (3\sin 1 + \sin 3) +2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n}(1)\frac {\sin 1\cos 2n-2n\cos 1\sin 2n} {1-4n^2}+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n-1}(1)\frac {\sin^2n+n\sin1\sin(1-2n)} {2n(1-n)}$$

Comment: This is a nice work ! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer.*

I also tried  the Jacobi–Anger expansion after @ТymaGaidash٠'s comment and faced the same problem.

What is amazing is that using
$$\cos (x+\cos (x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ (x+\cos (x))^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}$$
$$\int_0^1\cos (x+\cos (x))\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n }{(2 n)!}\int_0^1(x+\cos (x))^{2 n}\,dx$$ we face quite simple integrals (even if the general form is not obvious without using the binomial expansion).

$$I_{m,n}=\int x^m\cos^n(x)\,dx=\frac{x^{m-1} \cos ^{n-1}(x)}{n^2}\,(m \cos (x)+n x \sin (x))+$$
$$\frac{n-1} n\int x^m\cos^{n-2}(x)\,dx-\frac{m(m-1)}{n^2}\int x^{m-2}\cos^n(x)\,dx$$

The convergence is quite fast.

Computing the partial sums and converting the results to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 1 & 0.087897864304 \\
 2 & 0.233507419503 \\
 3 & 0.223845784451 \\
 4 & 0.224199417730 \\
 5 & 0.224191183570 \\
 6 & 0.224191316514 \\
 7 & 0.224191314937 \\
 8 & 0.224191314952 \\
 9 & 0.224191314951 \\
 10 & 0.224191314951 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$